# FB.init globally for Angular2

Tags: angular, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using FB SDK for multiple components in my angular2 application. I am trying to FB.init the application once and have that globally usable in multiple components. Where should I initialize the FB variable, so I don't need to do it in each component I'm using the FB variable. Is creating a service the direction to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a Service Wrapper for the Facebook SDK is indeed the thing to do, you can take a look at [ng-facebook-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-facebook-sdk) as an example, or simply use it in your application and avoid the development of this feature.